# Show that the functions $g_{n}(z)$=nf(z/n) converge uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ and find the limit function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be continuous function on $\mathbb{C}$ which is complex differentiable at $z=0$. Show that the functions $g_{n}(z)=nf(z/n)$ converge uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ and find the limit function. 
I think the function will converge at $f'(0)$. But can't prove anything.

Comment: I think you are missing the condition $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I also think so. If $f(0)=0$ then we can calculate the differentiation. But I have given the question in a way I have got it.

Comment: The result as stated is false. If $f(z)=1$ then $g_n(z)=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f(0)=0$, and $g(z)=zf'(0)$.

For any $z\in K$ compact,  $|g_n(z)-g(z)|\le |z\frac{f(z/n)}{z/n} - zf'(0)| \le |z| |\frac{f(z/n)}{z/n}-f'(0)|\le C a_n $ with $C=\sup_K |z| \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_n\to 0$.
Take the $\sup$ over $z\in K$ and then you have uniform convergence of $g_n\to g$.